# How to Link to all posts that have the Standard Post Format

Tags: posts, post-formats

Why doesn't this work?! `<?php echo get_post_format_link('standard');?>`

:( Any hints? All the other formats work.

Comment: http://www.wproots.com/using-wordpress-post-formats-to-their-fullest/ Down the bottom there's a snippet about archives.

Comment: "Standard" is *not* a post format - it's the **absence of a post format**. Therefore, when no post format is set (ie: standard post), the `post-format-*` taxonomy is not set, and the call `get_term_link()` used in this function will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your function.php

```
function akv3_query_format_standard($query) {
    if (isset($query->query_vars['post_format']) &&
        $query->query_vars['post_format'] == 'post-format-standard') {
        if (($post_formats = get_theme_support('post-formats')) &&
            is_array($post_formats[0]) && count($post_formats[0])) {
            $terms = array();
            foreach ($post_formats[0] as $format) {
                $terms[] = 'post-format-'.$format;
            }
            $query->is_tax = null;
            unset($query->query_vars['post_format']);
            unset($query->query_vars['taxonomy']);
            unset($query->query_vars['term']);
            unset($query->query['post_format']);
            $query->set('tax_query', array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'terms' => $terms,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                )
            ));
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'akv3_query_format_standard');
```

[More information here.](http://alexking.org/blog/2012/01/05/wp_query-by-standard-post-format)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
'showposts' => 9,
'tax_query' => array(
        array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => array('post-format-video','post-format-quote'),
              'operator' => 'NOT IN'
              )
        )
);
query_posts( $args );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

from

http://www.tristarwebdesign.co.uk/blog/wordpress/query-by-post-format-in-wordpress/

Comment: ...yeah that's great for displaying them, which isn't my problem. I just want to link to them on their "archive" page if that makes sense.  I guess I could create a custom archive page to display only the standard post formats and then link to it, but that's kind of a pain in the ass, don't you think? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Unfortunately I believe this is the only way to currently do this. As miqronaut explains below, there is no identifiable record added to the db linking a post as a 'standard' format. Only solution seems to be excluding all other formats for now. I ended up having to create a custom archive page with a custom loop similar to the one above to accomplish the same thing you are asking.

Comment: It's a tricky thing to do, I thought they would have sorted it out by now to be honest!

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a non-Standard post format to a post, a record gets added to the wp_term_relationships table. This record contains your post number and the term_taxonomy_id, which joins via wp_term_relationships to the post format in wp_terms. When you assign a Standard post format to a post, no record for post format is added to wp_term_relationships. If it was previously assigned another post format and changed to Standard, the record is removed from wp_term_relationships. Unfortunately, get_post_format_link relies on having that record in wp_term_relationships, so won't work with Standard post format.

For example, when I changed a post's post format to image, a record was added to wp_term_relationships, which eventually pointed to wp_terms >> post-format-image. When I changed the post's post format to Standard, this record disappeared. In WP's codebase, get_post_format_link uses get_term_by('slug', 'post-format-' . $format, 'post_format' ), and with the missing related post format record for Standard, we all lose. :-D

This might answer your original question of why it doesn't work. I wish that I could offer a slick solution, especially given your immensely helpful WordPress posts!

Comment: miqronaut - Thanks for your explanation. I suspected something like this was the case. Seems like so much work to have to exclude all other formats in order to show the most normal kind of post ;)  I'd say this is a borderline bug but I'm sure it probably affects very few people. I was just hoping there was an easier way that I was somehow missing.